# ASP.NET compartilha recursos no mesmo pool?

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis-7

Tenho hoje em meu IIS 8 sites em ASP.NET utilizando o mesmo pool.
Em média eles consomem 800mb de RAM.

Acabei desmembrando eles (pools separados) e pelo visto parece está consumindo 1,5GB no total.

Gostaria de saber se o IIS compartilha recursos no mesmo pool?

Ex: o Entity Framework.dll ele é carregado uma única vez e utilizado entre todos os sites do mesmo pool?

Pois diversas .dll são iguais para quase todos os projetos:
Ex:

```
    Antlr3.Runtime.dll
    EntityFramework.dll
    EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
    Newtonsoft.Json.dll
    System.Web.Mvc.dll
    WebGrease.dll
    //etc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível compartilhar recursos do IIS como você mencionou, mas não automático. Para fazer isso. é necessário configurar seu IIS para isso. Pode ver um pouco [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20775041/4843158). Também tem alguns exemplos [aqui](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sateesh-arveti/archive/2011/11/30/look-at-sharing-common-assemblies-in-asp-net-4-5.aspx) e [aqui](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/aspnet-and-visual-studio-2012/whats-new#_Toc_perf_3).

### Mas porque aumentou o consumo de memória então?

Cada pool de aplicativo é uma instância de **W3wp.exe**, um processo de trabalho para um/conjuntos de sites. Ou seja, quando estava no mesmo *pool*, estava criando apenas uma instância, consumindo assim mesmo memória.

### Então devo deixar tudo no mesmo pool de aplicação?

Não é bem assim, cada caso é um caso. O StackOverflow, por exemplo, deixa tudo em um único *pool*, como a [Roberta fala em sua palestra](http://www.infoq.com/br/presentations/a-arquitetura-do-stack-overflow-e-stack-exchange), mas isso significa que se algum der problema e para o pool, todos os sites pararão de funcionar.

Em resumo, você deve estudar o que é melhor para seu caso. Pode compartilhar recursos entre *pools* diferentes, colocar no mesmo ou se não tiver problema com a memória, deixar da forma que está.

> Nota: ao compartilhar os recursos (dll's), deverá garantir que estão os sistemas estão utilizando a mesma versão, podendo ter problemas se algum estiver em versão diferente.

Comment: O aumento do consumo da Ram tbm pode ser outros fatores como volume nos acessos, etc. Porém fiquei imaginado se não era o compartilhamento, pois o primeiro acesso em um site sempre é lento depois é rápido. Mas eu nunca tinha configurado o iis para compartilhar

Comment: @Dorathoto O primeiro acesso é lento por alguns fatores, o mais provável é o caching, mas isso já é outra coisa. Os acessos eu não sei dizer (sem monitorar), mas aumentar 50% praticamente eu diria que não é pelos acessos. Agora, o processo pode ser o fator chave. Você pode monitorar para ter certeza, mas aí também já é outro assunto. No demais, espero ter ajudado.